# Git add from specified directory. How?

Tags: git

I am following the symfony2 tutorial http://www.slideshare.net/weaverryan/symfony2-get-your-project-started. On slide 22 i must perform a git add .

I have github open and have a public repository helloise/helloises.

I want to add and commit to the above.

I also followed the commands on slide 17 which stated i must do a git init and a git status.

My directory structure is:

```
~/symfony2/Symfony$ ls -lah
total 56K
drwxr-xr-x  8 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 16:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 15:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 14:11 app
drwxr-xr-x  2 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 14:03 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 1.6K 2012-01-06 08:56 deps
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises  830 2012-01-06 08:56 deps.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 16:01 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises   91 2012-01-16 15:41 gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 1.1K 2012-01-06 08:56 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises    0 2012-01-16 16:00 README
-rw-r--r--  1 helloises helloises 6.3K 2012-01-06 08:56 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 14:03 src
drwxr-xr-x 13 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-16 14:11 vendor
drwxr-xr-x  3 helloises helloises 4.0K 2012-01-06 08:56 web
```

Comment: I don't know if you are willing to -or have the time for- learning the basics of Git properly, but that is what I would recommend you (I was in your same position just a few months ago). These links may help with that: Git basics: http://progit.org/book/ch2-2.html, Github setup: http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/ (mac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question very well. But if the situation is:

- You create a local git repo using git --init
- You have remote repo on github
- You want to "connect" your local repo with your github repo

What you must do is configure the remote repo in your local repo.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:helloise/helloises.git
```

Then put your files in the index and make a commit

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

and push the files to the remote repo

```
git push origin master
```

Read [this](http://caiustheory.com/adding-a-remote-to-existing-git-repo) for more info.

Comment: yup that's exactly what i wanted to know. thanks! understand know how things fit together :)

Answer (score 0):

Just as it says in the tutorial:

```
git add .
```

makes the repository track your current directory

```
git commit -am "Initial commit"
```

commits the files to the repository

```
git push origin master
```

to upload your repository to github